# Where can I download the larger resolution MNIST database?

Tags: database, neural-network, mnist

I'm training my neural network framework with MNIST datasets. I also know EMNIST, which is an extension of MNIST, but both are low-resolution(28*28) databases. And I want a high-resolution(56*56 or larger better) database of MNIST, can you tell me how to download high-resolution MNIST?

Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for generating high resolution MNIST images: http://blog.otoro.net/2016/04/01/generating-large-images-from-latent-vectors/ which can be helpful. Anyway, if you have a source of original MNIST high resolution images, it would be great if you could publish it here, I am also looking for one.